# how to extract one type from object literal type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

for example i have this type:`type mixed = {k1: string, k2: number}`

now i want another type(could be generated from some generic) with only `string` property type from `mixed`, like this:

`type stringOnly = {k1: string}` where `k2` from `mixed` is omitted.

How to do this in typescript? Thanks!

Comment: Translating the answer to the other question here yields [this](https://tsplay.dev/KWzrkW)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove a specific property for the new type, you can use `Omit`:

```
type stringOnly = Omit<mixed, "k2">;
```